# NullPointerException when adding adroid:id in <include>. What is the reason?

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have basically an empty application.
There is a toolbar though which has its own layout file and is being added to `activity_main.xml` with `<include>`.

If, however, the include contains `"android:id="@+id/toolbar"` it causes the app to crash with a NullPointerException when inflating the menu of the toolbar.

namely: `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)`

[MAIN ACTIVITY]

```
package com.hooni.nbun1kotlin

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.toolbar.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            if (it.itemId == R.id.settings) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Huhu ^^", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            true
        }

    }
}
```

[ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_test"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[TOOLBAR.XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:title="Toolbar" />
```

[MENU_MAIN.XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

[ERROR MESSAGE]

> 2019-09-10 14:16:14.334 6447-6447/com.hooni.nbun1kotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.hooni.nbun1kotlin, PID: 6447
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hooni.nbun1kotlin/com.hooni.nbun1kotlin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(int)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(int)' on a null object reference
>           at com.hooni.nbun1kotlin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

I dont understand the connection between, inserting/removing "android:id="@+id/toolbar_test" and the NullPointerException.

Much help is appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: The `android:id` on an `<include>` overrides the `android:id` on the root `View` in the included layout, so your `Toolbar` has ID (and therefore synthetic name) `toolbar_test` in `MainActivity` when you do that.

Comment: replace toolbar xml wiith this           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp" app:menu="@menu/menu"
    app:title="Toolbar" />